# Generic class to identify Current Session information in ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller, base-class

I'm developing a simple Custom Role-based Web Application using ASP.Net MVC, In my login Action, I'm creating a Profile session as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                var employeeProfile = AccountBal.Instance.GetEmployee(loginId);
                Session["Profile"] = employeeProfile;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", @"The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And I'm checking this or using this session in all Controller Actions as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(MyModel model)
{
    var employee = (Employee) Session["Profile"];
    if (employee == null) 
       return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Functionality goes here....
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can move this piece of session checking code in a base class or centralized class? so that, I do not need to check it every time in a Controller Actions instead I will access the properties directly

say,

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(MyModel model)
{
    var employee = _profileBase.GetCurrentProfile();
    if (employee == null) 
       return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Functionality goes here....
    }
}
```

Comment: inherit your controller with `BaseController` and in that controller write method `GetCurrentProfile()` and add your session code `GetCurrentProfile` inside it and use this method like `var employee = GetCurrentProfile();` in your desired controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base controller that contains your `GetCurrentProfile` method to retrieve current user profile like

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public Employee GetCurrentProfile()
    {
        return (Employee)Session["Profile"];
    }

    public bool SetCurrentProfile(Employee emp)
    {
        Session["Profile"] = emp;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And inherit your desired controller with above `BaseController` and access your `GetCurrentProfile` method like below

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult SetProfile()
    {
        var emp = new Employee { ID = 1, Name = "Abc", Mobile = "123" };

        //Set your profile here
        if (SetCurrentProfile(emp))
        {
            //Do code after set employee profile
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetProfile()
    {
        //Get your profile here
        var employee = GetCurrentProfile();

        return View();
    }
}
```

`GetCurrentProfile` and `SetCurrentProfile` directly available to your desired controller because we directly inherit it from `BaseController`.

You may use`try/catch` in above code snippet.

Try once may it help you

Comment: @55SK55, view the answer might be it help you :)